Wordpress Multisite Network Enables Theme
I have fifteen sites on a WordPress Network. The first site is the master site and content is copied to the the other child sites.
On my master site, I use theme patterns. The patterns work fine on the master site, but not on the child sites. I get an error message "Block has been deleted or is unavailable."
I can re-create the pattern on the child site but it will have different IDs. How can I use the synced pattern on the master site on the child sites?
Network enabl the theme and activate on each of the child sites, but the patterns dont appear in the theme editor on the child / subsite only on the master.
